# How to insert and update for view count in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I count the view value in mysql table. If the first user like the post in the **viewdetails** table insert a row with **Counts** column  value 1, If the next user like the post just update the **Counts** column(previous **Counts** value +1) ,without check anything.

 So I tried and take a sytax from internet **Duplicate Key**, but I don't know how to used it.

I tried below

```
INSERT INTO viewdetails
  (PostID,Counts)
VALUES
  (1, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  Counts     = VALUES(Counts)+1
```

**The above example is working like below**
1st execution
Insert Counts => 2

2nd execution
Update Counts => 2

3rd execution
Update Counts => 2

**But I need like below**
1st execution
Insert Counts => 1

2nd execution
Update Counts => 1+1

3rd execution
Update Counts => 2+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VALUES(Counts)` refers to the `input`, not the value in the table. Try something like:

```
INSERT INTO viewdetails
  (PostID,Counts)
VALUES
  (1, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  Counts = Counts+1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO viewdetails
 (PostID,Counts)
VALUES
  (1, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Counts   = Counts + 1;
```

`VALUES(col_name)` in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause refers to the value of `col_name` that would be inserted